# Como podria realizar un insert con otro valor que no es el del campo, Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Me explicare mejor aquí porque no se si el titulo quedo muy claro,

Tengo dos tablas

etlendpointmodel que tiene los siguientes atributos: id, endpoint_name

Aquí es donde voy a introducir una serie de nombres

```
INSERT INTO etlendpointmodel (endpoint_name) VALUES
     ('Producto');
```

Y tengo también otra tabla etlendpointconfig que es la relación entre los nombres de los archivos y el etlendpointmodel y tiene los siguientes atributos: endpoint_target, endpoint_model_id

El endpoint_target es una string aqui no hay el problema.

```
INSERT INTO etlendpointconfig (endpoint_target,endpoint_model_id) VALUES
     ('producto_<%Y%m%d>.csv',1);
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, en el atributo endpoint_model_id le tengo que pasar la id del
etlendpointmodel, pero yo lo quiero hacer con endpoint_name tendiendo en cuenta de que este campo es unique, sin cambiar la relacion entre las tablas, hay alguna forma de crear este filtro que me relacione el nombre con la id en un insert por varios elementos de golpe ?

ejemplo de lo que digo

```
INSERT INTO etlendpointconfig (endpoint_target,endpoint_model_id) VALUES
     ('producto_<%Y%m%d>.csv', 'Producto');
```

Comment: La redacción de tu pregunta es algo confusa y el ejemplo no es claro. Me pregunto si este tipo de problemas no es mejor resolverlo con un `TRIGGER` y/o definiendo restricciones de integridad referencial ¿? Convendría que expliques con mayor claridad el problema, y que des un ejemplo más detallado, pues no se logra entender del todo ni el problema ni el resultado final esperado, ni el contexto.

Comment: Si se puede, pero lo que te digo es que los nombres cambian, los id no. Las relaciones deberían implementarse siempre por el id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar directamente el nombre, por más único que sea, en el insert.

Pero si puedes valerte de ese nombre para obtener el ID a insertar. Tienes básicamente dos opciones:

Puedes hacer un insert con el resultado de un select que obtenga, junto a los otros valores a insertar, el ID, por ejemplo:

```
insert into etlendpointconfig (endpoint_target, endpoint_model_id) 
select 'producto_<%Y%m%d>.csv', id
  from etlendpointmodel
 where endpoint_name = 'Producto'
```

Otra opción es hacer un select solo del ID en dónde corresponde en `values`:

```
insert into etlendpointconfig (endpoint_target, endpoint_model_id) 
VALUES (  'producto_<%Y%m%d>.csv'
        , (select id from etlendpointmodel where endpoint_name = 'Producto')
       );
```